# default Type argument with same Type nonType argument to template

Tags: c++, templates

Ok so how can I declare C before using it ? Or is this not possible ?

```
// g++ error: 'C' has not been declared
// syntax error : identifier 'C'

template<C v, typename T, typename C = size_t> 
class keyedType {
    typedef T type;
    static constexpr C index = v;
};
```

Comment: You have to declare `typename C` *before* you use it. Unfortunately you then can't give it a default type.

Comment: Precisely that's the conundrum. Arguments with default values have to be towards the end.

Comment: Would a shorter alias be sufficient? If you have `template <typename T, typename C, C v> class keyedType { ... }` and `template <typename T, size_t v> using keyedTypeAlias = keyedType<T, size_t, v>;`, you can use `keyedType<T, size_t, v>` and `keyedTypeAlias<T, v>` interchangeably.

Comment: This works in g++ but doesn't in VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can sidestep it by making the `v` template argument have a default value as well, like in

```
template<typename T, typename C = size_t, C v = C()> 
class keyedType {
    typedef T type;
    static constexpr C index = v;
};
```

Comment: Nice idea but the default value is undesirable as I want to enforce that it is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this as follows.

An improved solution using nested classes.

```
template<typename I = size_t > class IdxType { 
    public : typedef I type; 

    template< I::type v, typename T> class keyedType {
    typedef T type;
    static const typename I::type index = v;
};
 };

// Use a follows.
IdxType<>::keyedType<0,char>

//A different type.
IdxType<long>::keyedType<5, int>
```

Nesting / Inheritance seems to be a way to sequence arguments when needed. Is useful even for specifying trailing arguments after varidic args.

Other solutions considered include using inheritance to sequence the arguments with default parameters to be declared ahead. One corollary of these is that I can now pass in arguments with defaults at any position.
    template class keyIndexType { public : typedef T type; };
    template class anotherIndexType { public : typedef T type; };

```
template< template<typename = size_t> class keyType
            , typename keyType<>::type v, typename T
        > class keyedType {
    typedef T type;
    static const typename keyType<>::type index = v;
};


// Use a follows.
keyedType<keyIndexType , 0,char>

//Need to define a new template if we want to change the type and then use as follows.
keyedType<anotherIndexType, 5, int>
```